# Qt 5.12.1 with Visual Studio2017, build from command line

Tags: c++, qt, cmd

I linked Qt5.12.1 with Visual Studio 2017.

I want to use Qt's cmd.exe terminal to qmake an application. But, each time I open the Qt's cmd.exe terminal, it tells that

```
Setting up environment for Qt usage...
Remember to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup!
```

So I must to run vcvarsall.bat, and only then I can qmake. But I think that is too troublesome. Are there any ideas to solve that problem, so that I wouldn't need to manually run vcvarsall.bat every time I open the cmd.exe terminal.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Please verify I got it right.

Comment: Yes,thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

See existing Qt bug reports about the same issue you have discovered like [1](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-29976) and [2](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31561). Unfortunately, you can't avoid it in Qt 5 until the issue is fixed (if ever).

But I think you could check `properties` of the Qt command prompt entry (press right mouse button on top of the entry which you clicked to open the command prompt) in Start menu to see which bat file it's calling and edit that script.

I think you could add something like below to the end of the bat file to get vcvarsall called automatically. *Check where vccarsall.bat is located in your VS version* and depending on your environment use either `x86` or `amd64`. Note that the following line is only to get you an idea how to call another bat file from a bat file, this line sets VS2015 64bit env.

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!